# Caml query filtering doesn't work, showing all items

Tags: date, sharepoint, filter, caml

I am using a caml query to filter items that were modified within the last 7 days. Somehow it returns all my items not only the modified ones.

`var viewXml = "<Query><Where><And><Gt>" + "<FieldRef Name=\"Modified\"/><Value Type=\"DateTime\"/><Today OffsetDays=\"-NumDays\"/>" + "</Value></Gt><Lt><FieldRef Name=\"Modified\"/><Value Type=\"DateTime\"/><Today OffsetDays=\"NumDays\"/>" + "</Value></Lt></And></Where></Query>";`

Why doesn't the filter work?

Marco

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <Where>
      <Gt>
         <FieldRef Name='Modified' />
         <Value Type='DateTime'>
            <Today Offset='-7' />
         </Value>
      </Gt>
   </Where>
```

Comment: Tried the offered suggestion but still getting all items as a result